# Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found

Tags: error

I've I clients website which has been working fine, today the site has gone down randomly. I was initially able to access the control panel and all seemed fine, whilst logged in the home page displayed a error 28 message which  understand means the database has run out of room. The client had checked with the host who said all was fine their end. But now the site is displaying "Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found" and I can't access the control panel any more?? Has anyone got any suggestions of how this could have come about or more importantly how it can be fixed. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please mark Ian answer as solution for your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Double check the database.php settings file. It's most likely to be some kinda of database connection issue. It may be that your host has changed the IP of it's DB server or something is blocking the connection.

See if you can log into the database directly through your hosting control panel or phpMyAdmin with the same credentials.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, it was down to the hosting, they fixed something at their end and the site is back up and running now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen once with a client's site recently. It ended up being the server. It was out of writable space in one of the cache/temp directories. But maybe you can try deleting all EE cache and see where that gets you.

We ended up switching hosts for the client and everything is back to normal.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, it was down to the hosting, they fixed something at their end and the site is back up and running now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is file permissions on config.php, database.php and the cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it's intermittent... this will likely be related to max database connections. Check the max user connections setting, and compare that to the number of connections open.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `database.php` file.
In my case, I resolved just changing hostname from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes for this error. One is database connection issues. Two, in my case, the host company upgraded PHP on the server and my EE installation became incompatible with the new version of PHP. I could role back to a legacy version of PHP for my host account, and that solved the problem.